# Detect a press of *some key* and *+* with keyboard module

Tags: python, keyboard

So I do: `if keyboard.is_pressed("shift + +"):`
And it gives me an error.

I need it to be in the same 'command'.
Please don't post this as an answer:

`if keyboard.is_pressed("shift") and keyboard.is_pressed("+"):`

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason it doesn't work is due to how `keyboard` parses this "hotkey" string. This is from the source code:

```
    for step in _re.split(r',\s?', hotkey):
        keys = _re.split(r'\s?\+\s?', step)
```

It just splits on "+" so you end up with `["shift", "", ""]`, which has two empty strings, hence an error.

You can do it like this:

```
if keyboard.is_pressed([sc1, sc2]):
```

where `sc1` and `sc2` are the "scan codes" of the keys you want.
For example, it might look like this:

```
if keyboard.is_pressed([56, 89]):
```

To find the scan codes, use a script like this:

```
import keyboard

while True:
    print(keyboard.read_event().scan_code)
```

Just run that script and press the keys you are interested in to see their scan codes get printed. Use these for `sc1` and `sc2` in the first code block in this answer.

From reading the source code, this should also work:

```
if keyboard.is_pressed(["shift", "+"]):
```

but it doesn't work for me. Maybe it will work for you.

Warning: This `keyboard` module will sometimes have different scan_codes for different keyboards and different operating systems.

Comment: Nah, it just prints "+". Maybe that's because my keyboard isn't English?

Comment: OK I made an update to my answer for you to try. Basically, try using the `scan_code` number of the key.

Comment: OK I have a sure way of doing this. I'm going to edit my whole answer. give me 2 minutes.

Comment: I have finished editing my answer. You should be able to do what you want with that information now. The main trick is - use a list.